# Fonts Localhost v Server

Tags: php, css

This one is driving me mad.
I have a completely unadulterated template which I have on my localhost and have uploaded to my server.
Identical files in both setups.

However my fonts are not rendering as they should on the server.

I've narrowed it down to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700">
```

If I comment this out on my local host I get the exact same render issues as I get on the server with this line in place. Clearly the server is not reading and using these style sheets.

Anybody seen this - Where can I go look to solve this?

thanks
Simon

Comment: web dev tools will tell you if the page is actually being requested by the server hosted file.

Comment: Are your fonts coming from google fonts?  If you comment that line out, you lose your google fonts.

Comment: To clarify:
The link above is the one that brings in fonts.

It works local host but does NOT work when I run the same page on the server.

So there must be a reason why my server side set up doesnt read this file.

I did a check to see if this was what was going wrong by commenting out the localhost line of code. I got the same issues I am having with my server view so I KNOW that its this link that is not working on my server.

Not sure why - is there a situation where a server has some kind of option to stop outside links?

Comment: try changing your link to this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700" type='text/css'>`

Comment: Thank you very much for the above - that was the issue - not sure why but it resolved everything for me.

Comment: You might be on an https page or have some security on your site.  Removing the HTTP allows your site to interpret the link as it wants to.  I'll add it as an answer just for future eyes

Answer (score 0):

There are some (and maybe more) things that might cause this:

- Is your server connected to the internet? (I know this sounds stupid, but who knows)
- Is the browser you're using on the server severely deprecated and could it use an update or two?
- Is there a firewall on the server that might block the browser's access to the internet?
- Try adding 'type="text/css" ' to the link tag somewhere and see if that makes a difference.
- Try surfing to http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700 and check that you're actually getting something.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your link from this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,70‌​0" type='text/css'>
```

Notice you're mainly just removing `http` from the line.  You might have some security on your server, maybe it's being read by an `https`which doesn't allow or like normal external links that are not secure.  So now your server can read it however it wants.